# How to remove one dictionary from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[image: df.head()]

And I made dictionaries from each unique *appId* as you see below:

[image: one dict]

with this command:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(timeseries.groupby('appId')))
```

After that I want to remove all dictionaries which have less than 30 rows from my dataframe. I removed those dictionaries from my dictionaries(dfs) and then I tried this code:

```
pd.concat([dfs]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `size` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.concat([dfs])
df = df[df.groupby('appId')['appId'].transform('size') >= 30]
#alternative 1
#df = df[df.groupby('appId')['appId'].transform('size').ge(30)]
#alternative 2 (slowier in large data)
#df = df.groupby('appId').filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 30)
```

Another approach is filter `dictionary`:

```
dfs = {k: v for k, v in dfs.items() if len(v) >= 30}
```

EDIT:

```
 timeseries = timeseries[timeseries.groupby('appId')['appId'].transform('size') >= 30] 
 dfs = dict(tuple(timeseries.groupby('appId')))
```

Comment: Thanks but I have problem with concat dictionaries, filtering dictionaries is not my problem.
when I do that it gives me this error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'dict'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: @yasi - how are created dictioaries?

Comment: @ jezrael I made them from one dataframe with this command:
dfs = dict(tuple(timeseries.groupby('appId')))

Comment: @yasi - In my opinion here is not reason for creating dictionaries in first step, first use `timeseries= timeseries[timeseries.groupby('appId')['appId'].transform('size') >= 30]` and then if necessary `dfs = dict(tuple(timeseries.groupby('appId')))`

Comment: Yes, thanks again jezrael! I had no Idea about this approach, It works well. I will edit my question and please make this as answer so I can confirm it.